# Error using sensor_msgs global variable

Tags: sensor-msgs, synchronization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

When trying to use global variables of type sensor_msgs I'm getting some errors running the code (compilation is done without errors), and I don't know what it referes. I declared the variables out of main:

```
const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr left_image;
```

And when trying to run the code, calling it in main, with any code (either std::cout , publish ....):

```
std::cout << "Time stamp (left image): "<< left_image->header.stamp << std::endl;
```

I get:

```
topic_sync2: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:418: T* boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator->() const [with T = const sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> >]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped
```

If anyone could help me I would be very grateful.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205847/error-using-sensor_msgs-global-variable/) by [aba92](https://answers.ros.org/users/21911/aba92/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2015-03-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You declare a NULL pointer here:

```
const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr left_image;
```

You have to assign the pointer to something before using it or create an object it can point to, like e. g.:

```
const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr left_image( new sensor_msgs::Image() );
```

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2015-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2